# Getting nameerror in python

Tags: python

I have the following function, I want to concat the 2 strings, What wrong am I doing here?

```
commands = ["abcd","123"]

def configure_dev(self, steps):
    func_name = self.id + ':configure dev'

    global conf_cmd
    for key in commands:
        conf_cmd += key + '\n'
    print(conf_cmd)
```

Getting the following error:

conf_cmd += key + '\n'

After running it, I get this error:
 `NameError: name 'conf_cmd' is not defined`

Comment: Where have you defined `conf_cmd`? `global` does not create a new variable.

Comment: you set it as global but it is undefined.

Comment: Thanks that was silly of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added your code with your critical issue resolved.

```
commands = ["abcd","123"]
def configure_dev(self, steps):
  func_name = self.id + ':configure dev'
  global conf_cmd = ''  //  <-- ''
  for key in commands:
    conf_cmd+=key+'\n'
  print(conf_cmd)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that every call to `configure_dev` will empty the string.

Comment: true.  Im not sure what his expectation was, but under the expectation of his coding, each time that function was called, he was planning to reinitialize it.  Or at least that is what i picked up from their code.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to add:
`conf_cmd = ''`

just after `commands = ["abcd","123"]`

Why?
`global conf_cmd` Does not create new string, it just means you can access the global variable.